# MySQL Group By two fields but count for two different groups?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

So let's say I have a big query that is grouping by column1 and column2 and performing a count. In the same query, how can I have a count grouped by column1? It could be a subquery but the prior group by is causing the problem. I've tried case and if statements but nothing seems to be working. The hard part is trying to get these two counts in the same query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: give sample data and expected result>

Comment: The second count is not clear to me. Do you want a count on grouped by fields?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column1_count
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column2_count
    ,other columns 
FROM table
```

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?!?

Comment: i just explained how to perform two count in one query.. remaining query will be as per requirement.